# How can I use AppleScript to see if a specific line of a .txt file matches a variable?

Tags: macos, applescript, text

I have a .txt file saved on my computer. The contents of the .txt file looks like this, for example:

[image]

I want my Automator application to read the **first** line of the .txt file and to put that line into a new variable. This is so that I can check if this variable matches another variable.

My ultimate goal is to have my application automatically write today's date to the top of the file and add an additional blank line beneath today's date. But I only want this to occur if today's date has not already been written to file, of course.

Here's the code that I have so far:

```
# Part 1
# Get and format today's date.

set TodayDate to current date
set y to text -4 thru -1 of ("0000" & (year of TodayDate))
set m to text -2 thru -1 of ("00" & ((month of TodayDate) as integer))
set d to text -2 thru -1 of ("00" & (day of TodayDate))
set FormattedTodayDate to y & "_" & m & "_" & d & " -"


# Part 2
# Get the first line of the .txt file.

set Target_Filepath to quoted form of "/Users/Me/Desktop/Documents/My Fruit Log.txt"

set FirstLineOfTxtFile to <this is where I need your help, Ask Different>


# Part 3
# Check to see if the first line of the .txt file is today's date.

set TodayDateAlreadyWritten to false

if FirstLineOfTxtFile contains FormattedTodayDate then
    set TodayDateAlreadyWritten to true
end if


# Part 4
# Write today's date to the first line of the .txt file (if necessary).

if TodayDateAlreadyWritten = false then

    set TextToWrite to FormattedTodayDate & "
    "       
    set OriginalText to quoted form of (do shell script "cat " & Target_Filepath)
    set TextToWrite to quoted form of TextToWrite & "\n" & OriginalText
    do shell script "echo " & TextToWrite & " > " & Target_Filepath

end if
```

It is *Part 2* where I am in need of assistance.

I may have made some mistakes in any of the parts of the above code (but none to my knowledge), so please feel free to correct me as you see fit.

These are my sources:

Part 1: [*Formatting short dates in AppleScript*](http://henrysmac.org/blog/2014/1/4/formatting-short-dates-in-applescript.html)

Part 4: [*How to prepend to text file in AppleScript?*](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/260381/how-to-prepend-to-text-file-in-applescript)

Comment: I've update the answer to address the _carriage return_ issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I believe I've narrowed down the `0D` bug in relation to using `cat` in the `do shell script` *command* and have modified the *code* so it doesn't introduce *carriage returns*, at least so far in testing just this *code* presented below. I would have to do further testing to see explicitly where the bug is however I've recoded it to use a `do shell script` *command* in a manner to write to the file without introducing *carriage returns*.

However I've commented out the first rewriting of Part 4 that uses the `do shell script` *command* because while not introducing *carriage returns* it does add an empty line to the end of target file each time it's runs and while not fatal nonetheless I'm not sure you'd want it to happen. So, I've added an alternate way not using a `do shell script` *command*.

Note that I prefer to use the camelCase naming convention for my variables, so I've rewritten all of the *code* adding additional *code* and *comments* as I prefer them. Sorry if this inconveniences you however I needed to do it in a manner that enabled me to effectively work through any issues. Feel free to modify as needed/wanted.

The *code* below works on the target file whether or not it initially contains ASCII Text content and I've verified on my system after multiple writes there are no *carriage returns* introduced and the original target file was first verified, whether empty or not, had no *carriage returns* and no *line feeds* were converted at any time as compared to other versions of *code* that caused this issue.

```
--    # Part 1 - Get and format today's date.

set todaysDate to (current date)
set y to text -4 thru -1 of ("0000" & (year of todaysDate))
set m to text -2 thru -1 of ("00" & ((month of todaysDate) as integer))
set d to text -2 thru -1 of ("00" & (day of todaysDate))

set formattedTodaysDate to y & "_" & m & "_" & d & " -" as string


--    # Part 2 - Get the first line of the target file.

set targetFilePathname to (POSIX path of (path to desktop as string) & "My Fruit Log.txt")

--    # Initialize firstLineOfFile variable in case the targetFilePathname file is empty.

set firstLineOfFile to ""
try
    --    # The commented line of code below is to be used when defining the actual code
    --    # in order to ensure a line feed "\n" is used and not a carriage return "\r".
    --    # Note that when compiled, the "\n" is converted to a literal newline
    --    # and a commented code line will be shown for all similiar instances.

    --    # set firstLineOfFile to first item of (read targetFilePathname using delimiter "\n")

    set firstLineOfFile to first item of (read targetFilePathname using delimiter "\n")
end try


--    # Part 3 - Check to see if the first line of the target file is today's date.

set isTodaysDateAlreadyWritten to false
if firstLineOfFile is equal to formattedTodaysDate then
    set isTodaysDateAlreadyWritten to true
end if


(*
--    # Part 4 - Write today's date to the first line of the target file, if necessary.

if isTodaysDateAlreadyWritten is equal to false then
    --    # set theTextToWrite to formattedTodaysDate & "\n"    
    set theTextToWrite to formattedTodaysDate & "\n"
    set theOriginalText to ""
    try
        set theOriginalText to (read targetFilePathname) as string
    end try
    --    # set theTextToWrite to theTextToWrite & "\n" & theOriginalText
    set theTextToWrite to theTextToWrite & "\n" & theOriginalText

    do shell script "echo " & quoted form of theTextToWrite & " > " & quoted form of targetFilePathname
end if
*)

--    # While the commented out Part 4 above does work by not introducing any carriage returns nonetheless
--    # it does introduce and additional empty line at the end of the target file and therefore will not be used.
--    #
--    # The following Part 4 does not use the do shell script command to make the writes nor does it add extra lines.


--    # Part 4 - Write today's date to the first line of the target file, if necessary.

if isTodaysDateAlreadyWritten is equal to false then
    --    # set theTextToWrite to formattedTodaysDate & "\n"    
    set theTextToWrite to formattedTodaysDate & "\n"
    set theOriginalText to ""
    try
        set theOriginalText to (read targetFilePathname) as string
    end try
    --    # set theTextToWrite to theTextToWrite & "\n" & theOriginalText
    set theTextToWrite to theTextToWrite & "\n" & theOriginalText
    try
        set referenceNumber to open for access targetFilePathname with write permission
        write theTextToWrite to referenceNumber starting at 0
        close access referenceNumber
    on error eStr number eNum
        display dialog eStr & " number " & eNum buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with title "File I/O Error..." with icon caution
        try
            close access referenceNumber
        end try
        return
    end try
end if
```

Comment: When I run your script, copied verbatim, I am presented with an error message stating, "File I/O Error...  File file My Fruit Log.txt is already open. number -49". This is despite the fact that the file is not open (and nor is TextEdit even running) when I run the script. I can't figure out why this error is being triggered. Even if the .txt file was open while I ran the script (which it is not), why should that prevent the script from reading and writing to the file?

Comment: Okay, this is very strange. When I run the script from a system-wide _Service_ (by clicking on the Service title under the Services menu found if you click on the current application title in the top-left corner of the screen), and **even if the .txt file really is open when I run the _Service_**, it runs successfully without error. But when I run the code from within Automator (by clicking the play-button-triangle labeled "Run" in the top-right corner of the screen), I am always presented with this error.

Comment: @rubik's sphere, This is a prime reason why proper and adequate error handling must be used. You may not think the file is open however if you get that error it's open! BTW open in this instance does does not mean it's visible or minimized, it means there a file handle open for that file. This means that `open for access` occurred on the file but was not closed by `close access ...`. Meaning that before you ran my new code you must have ran `open for access` and the file handle (referenceNumber) was never closed. Maybe from the other code in the other question. I know my present code is solid!

Comment: @rubik's sphere, I've copied this code directly out of my own answer and with or without the existence of the target file it works as coded and without any issue when run from Script Editor. I can add  `+ 86400 * 2` to the `set todaysDate to (current date)` line and increment the multiplier after the `*` each time I run it and it adds the next days date to the file as it's supposed to. You'll need to close the file handle to continue with the target filename or change the filename a bit for testing till you close the file handle on that named file.

Comment: @rubik's sphere, I tested this in Script Editor and Automator under OS X 10.11.6 and it just works! Even if I'm going to use AppleScript code in Automator I always write and test it under Script Editor first then copy it to Automator and only a few times have I had to modify the code in Automator other then what's expected to handle the overall workflow.

Comment: I quit Automator.app and then reopened Automator, and that instantly fixed the issue. I was not familiar with this meaning of "open"; I had thought that the error was saying that the file was literally minimized in the Dock or something. You're right - this was a nice lesson on the value of error handling. Thank you for your help. You have taught me a lot.

Comment: Very belatedly… per TN2065 (cf. How does do shell script get the result? How do I return a shell variable to my AppleScript?), 'do shell script' defaults to using 'return' and not adding a trailing empty line (perhaps a legacy Macintosh artefact). 

This is due to its default 'altering line endings' parameter (which perhaps nobody consciously adds). To see a more typical unixy/modern behaviour (i.e. linefeed and a trailing empty line) add 'without altering line endings'. The ASLG references this —poorly in my opinion— in its Commands Reference section.

Comment: @Mockman, RE: "Very belatedly… per TN2065" --  Better late than never! :) At the time I posted this  answer, I can't recall whether or not I had read that TN, but certainly have since then. Thanks though, as a reread of the TN never hurts to refresh ones memory.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello, for your part 2, a script shell script "head -n 1" will allow you to assign the value (text) of line 1 of your file to your variable FirstLineOfTxtFile and then to format your text like you Wish.**

```
set TodayDate to current date
set y to text -4 thru -1 of ("0000" & (year of TodayDate))
set m to text -2 thru -1 of ("00" & ((month of TodayDate) as integer))
set d to text -2 thru -1 of ("00" & (day of TodayDate))
set FormattedTodayDate to y & "_" & m & "_" & d & " -"

set Target_Filepath to quoted form of ""/Users/Me/Desktop/Documents/My Fruit Log.txt""

set FirstLineOfTxtFile to do shell script "head -n 1 '"/Users/Me/Desktop/Documents/My Fruit Log.txt"'"
set TodayDateAlreadyWritten to false

if FirstLineOfTxtFile contains FormattedTodayDate then
    set TodayDateAlreadyWritten to true
end if


# Part 4
# Write today's date to the first line of the .txt file (if necessary).

if TodayDateAlreadyWritten = false then

    set TextToWrite to FormattedTodayDate & "
    "
    set OriginalText to quoted form of (do shell script "cat " & Target_Filepath)
    set TextToWrite to quoted form of TextToWrite & "
" & OriginalText
    do shell script "echo " & TextToWrite & " > " & Target_Filepath

end if
```

Comment: Since the code you've provided won't compile as it has errors, I can only assume you didn't actually test it before posting it!

Comment: @user3439894 Can I encourage you to either edit the post or use a comment to be more specific about these errors?